# AWS CLI only do partial upload

Tags: amazon-web-services, cron

I have 2x cronjobs running overnight.
The first does a pg_dump of a database, the second upload the dump to the cloud picking the file from a mounted drive under Ubuntu that is synced with dropbox running on Mac (shared drive, necessary setup)

```
02 20 * * * '/home/user/Documents/Modules/pg_dump_okay_db.sh'
03 20 * * * touch /home/username/Desktop/touch00
04 20 * * * /home/user/Documents/Modules/okay_db2_to_aws_s3.sh'
```

pg_dump script

```
#!/bin/sh
########################################
#
# Backup database
#
########################################

PGUSER="XXXX" PGPASSWORD="XXXX" /usr/bin/pg_dump --format=c okay_db2 > '/media/share/Dropbox(Studio)/Post/_RESOLVEBACKUP/db2/'"okay_db2.resolve.$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S).bak"
```

aws cli script

```
#!/bin/sh
########################################
#
# Backup to S3 bucket
#
########################################

/usr/local/bin/aws s3 sync --delete '/media/share/Dropbox(Studio)/Post/_RESOLVEBACKUP/db2' s3://bucket-name/PostgreSQL/db2/
```

Both scrips works fine independently.
When I check my aws web browser the next morning, the latest update (let's say 1GB file). It's only 400mb or 600mb and I need to run the upload script manually. In that case it works

Is my crontab set up wrongly?

Comment: Are you sure that the dump completed before doing the upload? It might be better to chain the commands -- that is, trigger the upload when the dump is completed rather than at a specific time.

Comment: I tried to shift the upload of 6hours to be sure there's enough time between the two commands. I only know "sleep" and "&&" but I think they need a time variable to work.

Comment: Before initiating the sync, you should store some log information, etc `ls -l /media/share/..../db2 >/tmp/before_sync`. That will show you the directory before the sync. Then, compare it to what was uploaded. Also, send the output of the `sync` command to a log file with `>/tmp/sync_log` at the end.

Comment: Thanks
Would that be useful for a single file?

Comment: Logging is ALWAYS useful!

Comment: Did a test log and everything seems fine. It's outputting the all the partial uploads of the file.
I'm lost

Comment: Cleared up space on the drives (dedicated to postgres and dropbox one) also uploaded all utilities to latest version but nothing changed

Comment: Make sure you log a listing of the directory (including file sizes) *before* the copy process and also log a listing of the files on S3 *after* the copy process. If the file sizes don't match, then something is wrong with the copy process, but you'll need to prove that first.

Comment: I see.
How can I write the size information to a log? I've done this:

ls /media/share/Dropbox\ \(Okay)/Okay/_RESOLVEBACKUP/db2/ > /mnt/sdb1/tmp/user/logs/presync_log & /usr/local/bin/aws s3 sync --delete '/media/share/Dropbox (Okay)/Okay/_RESOLVEBACKUP/db2' s3://bucket/PostgreSQL/db2/ >/mnt/sdb1/tmp/user/logs/sync_log

and that's writing the content while the second part prints the output of aws s3 sync from the terminal which I guess I should improve to have a print from the AWS

Comment: Solved. Stupidly I swap hours with minutes!